# How to rename file(1).ext to file1.ext in php

Tags: php, escaping, file-rename, batch-rename

I want to convert pdf files into text files using xpdf converter with php.
The problem is the file names are file(1).pdf,file(2).pdf...The brackets are the problem.XPDF cannot read file names with brackets.So i want to change the name to file1.pdf,file2.pdf....(remove brackets)
I tried to use rename() in php in every possible way with escaping but still get either of two errors

=System cannot find the path code 2
=Directory,file,volume syntax is wrong or something... code 123

Please somebody help me.I want to do it in PHP itself.

what i used is..

```
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['number'];$i++)
{

    $filen2="\"d:/res/file(".$i.").pdf\"";
    $file="\"d:/res/files".$i.".pdf\"";
    rename($filen2,$file);
    echo "converting file ".$filen2."<br/>";
    shell_exec("D:/xpdf/bin32/pdftotext.exe $file");

}
```

and...

```
for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['number'];$i++)
{

    $filen2="\"d:\\res\\file(".$i.").pdf\"";
    $file="\"d:\\res\\files".$i.".pdf\"";
    rename($filen2,$file);
    echo "converting file ".$filen2."<br/>";
    shell_exec("D:/xpdf/bin32/pdftotext.exe $filen2");

}
```

right now i tried rename() on files without brackets...still it doesnt work...what could be wrong??XPDF worked for files without bracket without any problem

Comment: post the syntax that u hv used to rename

Comment: @user2401175 I didn't knew how to comment.I posted the syntax that day itself but forgot to mention your name in comment.actually the problem was a virus.Now it worked well after I reinstalled Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.Actually the problem was with my Windows.There was a f***** virus in it which prevented me from accessing advaned operations like changing PATH variable,opening control panel etc...Now i reinstalld Windows and every thing works just as expected..

The syntax of rename() is `rename(<path to file>,<path to the same file with new name>);`

for example to rename `D:\res\file(1).pdf` to `file1.pdf` i used the following code `rename('D:/res/file(1).pdf','D:/res/file1.pdf');`.It worked perfectly well. I also tried `rename('D:\\res\\file(1).pdf','D:\\res\\file1.pdf');` it also worked well.Wish I had reinstalled Windows earlier.